# glReadPixels: Stack around variable was corrupted after read pixels

Tags: opengl, stack, glreadpixels

I am trying to use glReadPixels() to read a window of 5 * 5 pixels. Here is the code.

```
const unsigned int WINDOW_SIZE = 5;
const unsigned int NB_COMPONENTS = 3;
GLubyte array[NB_COMPONENTS * WINDOW_SIZE * WINDOW_SIZE];
glReadPixels( 0, 0, WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, array);
```

Yet this code causes the following error in visual studio:
"Stack around variable array was corrupted"

If I add +4 to the size of the array it works fine. Does someone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `GL_RGB` make sure [`GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is set to `1`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPixelStore.xhtml).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I added glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);